# result returns more than one elements; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am doing library application. So, in that i need to search a book by its title .

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping(path="/viewBook")
public String viewBook(Book book,HttpServletRequest request)
{
    request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_VIEW");
            request.setAttribute("tb", bookService.findByTitle(book.getTitle()));
          return "homepage";


        }
```

**JSP page**

```
<c:when test="${mode=='MODE_VIEW' }">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h3>Add A Book</h3>
        <hr>
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="GET" action="/viewBook">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Enter Title</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title"
                                value="${book .title}" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="View" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</c:when>
```

**Service class**

```
public String findByTitle(String title) {

    return BookRepo.findByTitle(title);
}
```

**BookRepo**

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book,Integer> {

    public String findByTitle(String title);

}
```

**Book**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Boooks")
public class Book {


    public int id;
    private String author;
    private String title;



    public Book()
    {

    }
    public Book(String author, String title, int id) {
        super();
        this.id=id;
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
    }
    @Id
    //here comes getters and setters i have omitted them here.

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [id=" + id + ", author=" + author + ", title=" + title + "]";
    }


}
```

I am getting this error

> javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements

Comment: This error means that you are looking for a unique result, but you get more or less 1 row. For more help we need to see your service and dao classes

Comment: //Service class      public String findByTitle(String title) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return BookRepo.findByTitle(title);
}

Comment: Do not add code in a comment, add it to your question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52033195/edit) button

Comment: i have added it could you please check once and help me out

Comment: I Need also your bookRepo class and the table definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the title is unique in table.

```
bookService.findByTitle(book.getTitle())
```

This line is returning multiple rows from DB but your method in service or dao is expecting single unique result.

Check your service and dao classes for troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

This service is returning more than 1 element. In your code, you are expecting one string but your code is returning more than 1 string.

This code will work

//Service class

```
public List<String> findByTitle(String title) {

return BookRepo.findByTitle(title);
}
```

//BookRepo

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book,Integer> {

    public List<String> findByTitle(String title);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to findFirst prefix.

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book,Integer> {
   public Book findFirstByTitleIgnoreCase(String title);
}
```

The code above will return the first result when you have duplicate books.

An improvement when you need find for a string and a nice practice is to put the suffix `IgnoreCase` at the end of method name